# TFS - How can I retain folder level history when I Branch/Move sources?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, revision-history

We are restructuring our sources in TFS. I would like to move the sources to a different folder in the same TFS. While I move the sources, I would like to retain the history at a folder level (default is file level)
I found two options, both of them retain history at a file level but NOT folder level.
1. Branch: When I branch, the history at the folder level is lost.
2. Move/Rename: The history at the folder level is lost.

I would like to know if there is an option to move/branch sources and retain all the folder history. I found a VS extension plugin that shows the branched history (https://branchedhistory.codeplex.com/) but I cannot rely on that.

It would be great if you can help me. 
Fyi, A couple of years ago, we migrated our sources from TFS 2010 to 2012 and it retained all folder/file level history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use the extension plugin, can't be achieved in TFS directly. This has been a feature request in user voice. And this suggestion is still on the backlog, but they are not part of the 6-month plan.

> [Implement branch history for folders](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2276988-implement-branch-history-for-folders)
>
> Source:  UserVoice

However you can use a workaround as below:  You can go to the command line and view the non-recursive history for a folder to see the history across branches. However, this only shows the history of the folder itself, not the contents of that folder.